# trying to install tweaks on Odin 6 install, error writing libgranite5

Tags: settings

Long time windoze user, so I need it step by step please.  :)

I'm trying to install Elementary tweaks from Elementary-tweaks PPA.  I got the instructions from [this post](https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/tweaks.2549/).

The first answer said you just need to run a few commands to do it.  First, add PPA's:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

When I did that it worked fine.  Next step. add  Elelmentary-tweaks PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks && sudo apt-get update
```

That went fine too.  Then you install it:

```
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

When I do that, I get the following response (after entering password):

```
Preparing to unpack .../libgranite5_5.3.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgranite5:amd64 (5.3.0-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgranite5_5.3.0-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/metainfo/granite.appdata.xml', which is also in package libgranite-common 6.1.2+r2170+pkg121~ubuntu6.1
Selecting previously unselected package elementary-tweaks.
Preparing to unpack .../elementary-tweaks_1.0-0~202010170103~ubuntu6.0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking elementary-tweaks (1.0-0~202010170103~ubuntu6.0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgranite5_5.3.0-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
unknowable@Elite8300:~$
```

Looks like the relevant portion is here:

```
Unpacking libgranite5:amd64 (5.3.0-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgranite5_5.3.0-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/metainfo/granite.appdata.xml', which is also in package libgranite-common 6.1.2+r2170+pkg121~ubuntu6.1
```

That looks like I should remove libgranite6, install libgranite5, then reinstall libgranite6.  Unfortunately there's like a ton of stuff that depends on libgranite6.  Should I just notate everything that gets removed by removing libgranite6, then install libgranite5, then libgranite6, then just go through the list reinstalling every app that depended on libgranite6?

Sorry for the possibly stupid question, but I'm a new Linux user, and the one time I did install tweaks in Kubuntu it went fine.  Thank you for your patience and investment of time.  It won't go unappreciated.

Comment: Whoops, just realized I could have said *something* about what I'm running.  Fresh install of elementary OS 6 Odin.  Dual boot with Kubuntu 21.10 is it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elementary tweaks are not made for Odin. You should be installing Pantheon tweaks instead https://github.com/pantheon-tweaks/pantheon-tweaks

Comment: An admin said this doesn't answer the question, but it seems to me that it does perfectly. I tried for days to install Elementary Tweaks on elementary OS 6 Odin, but that version needs Pantheon Tweaks. I installed that in less than a minute, and it's been working fine since. Problem solved.

Comment: Glad to hear it.